# Get some string from data with php?

Tags: php

I have string like this `[1] Name : Bro Jhon<br>[2] Name : Japar S`

How to get `Bro Jhon` and `Japar S` and echo it?

What I've tried so far

```
$op = preg_match_all("/Name: (.*?)<br>/g",$x);
```

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: i already try `$op = preg_match_all("/Name: (.*?)<br>/g",$x);` but not work...Please i'm not understand about regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your regex into

```
Name\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\<br\>|$)
```

Problem with your regex are as follows

```
Name: (.*?)<br>
```

- Within your string you have `space` between `Name` & `:` i.e `Name :` and your regex is looking for `Name:` i.e. without `space`
- Other one is your regex will match for first value only i.e. before `<br>` and not for those which're at the `end of string`
- Also  you don't need to specify `g` modifier or it'll throw `warning` for the same
- `preg_match` returns value in `boolean` so for getting matches you need to `assign third parameter`.

So your PHP code looks like as

```
preg_match_all("/Name\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\<br\>|$)/",$str,$n);
print_r($n[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with this:

```
<?php
$subject = str_replace('<br>', "\n", '[1] Name : Bro Jhon<br>[2] Name : Japar S');
preg_match_all('/Name\s*:\s*(.*)/', $subject, $tokens);
print_r($tokens[1]);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bro Jhon
    [1] => Japar S
)
```

Comment: Simple regex! made use of `\n`. my +1

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the complete string.
Something like:

```
<?
    $str = "[1] Name : Bro Jhon<br>[2] Name : Japar S";
    //splits for each <br>
    $splitted_values = split("<br>", $str);
    //on each splitted string
    foreach($splitted in $splitted_values){
        //we obtainwhete the : is
        $pos = strpos(":", $splitted);
        //the we remove from left to right
        $name = substr($splitted, $pos);
        //some spaces are removed also
        $name = trim(name);
        //finally the echo
        echo $name;
    }
?>
```

Also, you could write a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

We can extract word like this,Sorry I am quite poor with recuring function.I hope this will help you.

```
function getWord_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = '[1] Name : Bro Jhon<br>[2] Name : Japar S';
$parsed = getWord_between($orgstring, 'Name :', '<br>');

echo $parsed;
```